# To be OK; To be fine

Tags: phrase-choice, synonyms

> 1. Most movies are fine with me.
> 2. Most movies are OK with me.

Are they both correct?
Are there any other options?

Comment: "with me" or "to me"? There are differences.

Comment: @Safira Both examples say *with me*. If you're referring to the title, I think it should be interpreted as "to be okay with me" vs "to be fine with me".

Comment: @WendiKidd: I mean this: *She looks fine with me* (meaning: she looks fine when she is with me), or *She looks fine to me* (meaning: I see her just fine). That's what I'm wondering.. *To me* and *with me* sound different to me.

Comment: @Safira You're correct, but as the OP's question only references *with me* I thought you were confused by the *to*s in the title. In that case, yes, there's a difference there, but I didn't think that was what the OP was asking, so I misinterpreted your comment!

Comment: So, is it ok to say Most movies are Ok to me?

Comment: It would help if you tried to explain what you are trying to say. That you like most movies? That, of the several options you have for going to the theater tonight, most of the movies seem okay? That you don't have any complaints about the movies? I don't really like either of those wordings very much, but it's hard to suggest an alternative when I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: "That, of the several options you have for going to the theater tonight, most of the movies seem okay?" <= This one.

Comment: @VijayaRagavan - I think we'd usually say, "Okay **with** me," not, "Okay **to** me." You might even hear "Okay **by** me."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those phrases are quite vague, and could refer to a number of things in general, such as:

- (A) I like most movies.
- (B) I don't have a problem with the movie industry.
- (C) Of the several options we have for going to the theater, most of the choices seem okay.

In our [conversation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/to-be-ok-to-be-fine#comment20533_11974), though, up in the comments, you indicated that the last option (C) is the one you are asking about.

So, let's imagine that a friend of mine listed five movies we could go watch, and I found four of those choices appealing at some level or another. I might say something like:

> - Most of those sound good.
> - I'm fine with most of those.
> - Pretty much any of those would be alright with me.

I think it's worth pointing out how the word *those* sounds more natural than the word *movies*. I probably wouldn't use the word *movies* at that point in the conversation, because that could be figured out from the context. (That may also be why some folks here had trouble understanding what you were asking; including the word *movies* in that context sounds unnecessarily "forced.")

In the third reply, notice how "pretty much" can be paired with "any" to mean "most" – the words "just about" could be used in the same way.

In a situation where I'm using some form of "most" to indicate "all but one", I'd be quite likely to clarify which of the options I'd like to strike from the list:

> - Just about any of those would be okay with me. I'd rather not go see *Ocean's 14*, though.

If all five choices sounded good to me, as opposed to four out of five, I would change the wording:

> - All of those sound good.
> - I'm fine with any of those.
> - Those are all alright with me.

And if there were only two:

> - Both of those sound good.
> - I'm fine with either of those.
> - Either of those would be alright with me.

Comment: `I'm fine with most of those.` Is "Most of those are fine with me" correct as well?

Comment: I have no problem with "Most of those are fine with me." You're getting the hang of this :^)

Comment: I agree, those phrases could refer to lots of things in general, but on the whole (regardless of their meaning from the context) it would seem that _fine_ is more common than _OK_ (source: Google Books). In other words, _I'm fine with most of those_ (and its reverse version _Most of those are fine with me_) is more used than _I'm OK with most of those_ (actually, the latter wouldn't seem correct). Do you agree?

Comment: Probably so, but it's hard to say for sure when people are talking conversationally. Other variants would include: _I'm cool with those, I don't have a problem with any of those,_ and even _those all sound peachy to me,_ although that last one would be said playfully – if I hear "peachy" used at all nowadays, it's in a rather playful and tongue-in-cheek way.

Answer (score 1):

There lies a difference between 'OK' and 'fine'. When you say 'fine', it reflects satisfaction. On the other hand, 'OK' seems 'passable' that means you actually expected something else but then the option given won't bother you much! You take it with no great troubles. See this:

> You got hurt a bit because someone pushed you in a line you are standing. When she/he apologizes, you reply "That's OK!". This means it hurt you but that's bearable. So here, by no means, you say 'That's fine!'.

In this context, if you are not pretty sure which movie you are talking about (like in this case), better use 'Most movies are OK to me'.

I agree @WendiKidd for using 'to'.